# Amazon AWS ProtocolException

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I developed a web app using ASP .NET MVC3.
I'm trying to get book info using Amazon AWS based on ASIN.
This is the code snippet that should to that:

```
AsinRequest req = new AsinRequest();
req.asin = "0596158106";
req.type = "lite";
req.tag = "webservices-20";
req.devtag = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
req.mode = "books";
req.locale = "US";
req.offer = "1";
req.offerpage = "1";
AmazonSearchPortClient amazonWS = new AmazonSearchPortClient();
ProductInfo prod = amazonWS.AsinSearchRequest(req);
Debug.WriteLine(prod.Details);
```

Every time I try to run it I get a HTTP 417 Expectation failed saying that it's a ProtocolException.

Instead of the X's I used the Access Key ID found in the Security Credentials section. I also tried using the Secret Access Key but it didn't make any difference.

I used this tutorial as a starting point:

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Using-the-Amazon-Web-Service

Does anyone know what could be causing it ?

Comment: Have you verified AWS still supports that method and those parameters.  The article is 6 years old and that API has changed since then.